# Is there a way to determine that SMM interrupt has occured?

Tags: x86, hardware, intel

Is there a way to determine from user space, for some progamatically defined interval, if a [SMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode) entry has occurred on the current core?

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Nehalem, the MSR register 0x34 (called `MSR_SMI_COUNT`) counts the number of SMIs that occurred since the system was booted. It's read-only and Intel-specific. You can programmability read from this register (or any other MSR register) from user mode using the `/dev/cpu/CPUNUM/msr` interface. There are several tools that use the interface to show the SMI count including [msr-tools](https://01.org/msr-tools/overview) (`sudo rdmsr -a 0x34`) and turbostat (`sudo turbostat --msr 0x34`).

I've extracted this code from the turbostat source code (/source/tools/power/x86/turbostat/turbostat.c). The `get_msr_fd` function returns the file descriptor of the `msr` file. The `get_msr` function accepts the CPU number, the MSR offset (0x34 for `MSR_SMI_COUNT`), and a pointer to a 64-bit location that will hold the value of the MSR (although `MSR_SMI_COUNT` is a 32-bit counter and the upper 32 bits are reserved).

```
int get_msr_fd(int cpu)
{
    char pathname[32];
    int fd;

    fd = fd_percpu[cpu];

    if (fd)
        return fd;

    sprintf(pathname, "/dev/cpu/%d/msr", cpu);
    fd = open(pathname, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
        err(-1, "%s open failed, try chown or chmod +r /dev/cpu/*/msr, or run as root", pathname);

    fd_percpu[cpu] = fd;

    return fd;
}

int get_msr(int cpu, off_t offset, unsigned long long *msr)
{
    ssize_t retval;

    retval = pread(get_msr_fd(cpu), msr, sizeof(*msr), offset);

    if (retval != sizeof *msr)
        err(-1, "cpu%d: msr offset 0x%llx read failed", cpu, (unsigned long long)offset);

    return 0;
}
```

An SMI may occur multiple times per second or may not occur for a long period of time. But one way to observe a change in `MSR_SMI_COUNT` is by issuing a synchronous SMI. Typically, this can be done by writing some 8-bit value to I/O port 0xB2 or 0xB3. You can refer to your chipset manual to determine which I/O ports may trigger an SMI.

Comment: `turbostat` version 17.06.23 includes a per-core SMI column by default.  Also, the syntax for adding a new column is `turbostat --add msr0x34,u64,cpu,delta,SMM` (I think, based on the --help example for TSC.  I didn't see any counts from that or the SMI column, running with no other args to just show a `vmstat`-style output printing a block of rows every 5 seconds :)

Comment: Another (easier?) way to trigger an SMI is to deliver it through the LAPIC. IDK if Linux has a specific function for that, `native_apic_mem_write(APIC_ICR, ...)` should do anyway.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I think that APIC_ICR can only be written to in kernel mode, right? Just like the I/O ports I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @HadiBrais Yes, only in kernel mode. Unless some driver exposes it, but that would be very dangerous.

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question, but I was targeting user space. I've added that detail now.